# Blockarray errors

Tags: errors, arrays

After inserting a second `blockarray`-environment in front of a first one I get a dozen error messages for lines where none appeared before. It seems to have to do with the inserted `blockarray`-environment. But as it is just copied and adjusted from the first one I don't see where the error is.
Errors are for example `Paragraph ended before \BA@beginblock was complete.` And for other lines it starts at the subsection `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \subsection` and `Missing } [and \cr] inserted. \subsection{Survey}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

...values is then taken, corresponding to the rules for
\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{blockarray}{rc}
    \begin{block}{rc\Right{\}}{= for odd number of frames \textit{n}}
        odd number of frames $n$ : & pix$_\frac{n+1}{2}$(x,y) \\
        even number of frames $n$ : & $\dfrac{1}{2}\left(pix_\frac{n}{2} + pix_{\frac{n}{2}+1}\right)$ \\
    \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\\
\begin{blockarray}{rc}
    \begin{block}{rc\Right{\}}{= Master-\textbf{Dark}[Bias]}}
        odd pixel values $n$ : & \textbf{Dark}[Bias]$_\frac{n+1}{2}$ \\
        even pixel values $n$ : & $\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\mathbf{Dark}\mathrm{[Bias]}_\frac{n}{2} + \mathbf{Dark}\mathrm{[Bias]}_{\frac{n}{2}+1}\right)$ \\
    \end{block}
    & \\
    \begin{block}{rc\Right{\}}{= Master-\textbf{Dark}$_\mathbf{Flat}$[Bias]}}
        odd pixel values $n$ : & \textbf{Dark}$_\mathbf{Flat}$[Bias]$_\frac{n+1}{2}$ \\
        even pixel values $n$ : & $\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\mathbf{Dark}_\mathbf{Flat}\mathrm{[Bias]}_\frac{n}{2} + \mathbf{Dark}_\mathbf{Flat}\mathrm{[Bias]}_{\frac{n}{2}+1}\right)$ \\
    \end{block}
\end{blockarray}

\subsection{Survey}
...
\end{document}
```

Also, I am asking myself what are the options  for at the beginning of a block like `{= Master-\textbf{Dark}$_\mathbf{Flat}$[Bias]}}` as they are not shown in my pdf?

Comment: The posted example makes the error `! LaTeX Error: Environment blockarray undefined.` Please fix: **remove** every package not needed for the example and **add** the packages that are needed.

Comment: The error is because as it states in the error message you are missing a `}` this argument is never finished `\begin{block}{rc\Right{\}}....` there is no matching closing brace.

Comment: Note that the error message is surprisingly accurate both in the problem and location, you do not quote the relevant part. the error message is: `Runaway argument?
{rc\Right {\}}` which is the exact problem "runaway argument" is what tex calls an argument with no closing `}` and the offending argument is the one shown in the message.

Comment: unnecessary packages removed

Comment: I guess you still haven't tested the document as posted or addressed the error message in the first comment.

Comment: yes I did. But I don't receive the same error messages as you and my messages refer only to the whole environment without more exact relevant parts. But admittedly, I have to add `blkarray` package.

Comment: The missing blkarray package was exactly the cause of the error message in the first comment. If you ran the document as posted then you would have got exactly the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Your code was lacking a  `}` to close the preamble of the first `blockarray` environment. Also, it appears the text on the right of the braces (`\Right{\}}{some text}}`: has 0-width in the blockarray environment. A work around to achieve centring of this environment consists in adding after `\end{blockarray}` an `\hphantom{some text}`. Though not perfect, it seems to produce an (almost) correct centring:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,abstracton]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Schriftsatz Dokument
\usepackage{lmodern} %use this package in combination with [T1]{fontenc} wo have vector-graphics letters instead of pixelated letters
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

...values is then taken, corresponding to the rules for
\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{blockarray}{rc}
 \begin{block}{rc\Right{\}}{= for odd number of frames \textit{n}}}
 odd number of frames $n$ : & pix$_\frac{n+1}{2}$(x,y) \\
 even number of frames $n$ : & $\dfrac{1}{2}\left(pix_\frac{n}{2} + pix_{\frac{n}{2}+1}\right)$ \\
 \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\\
\begin{blockarray}{rc}
 \begin{block}{rc\Right{\}}{= Master-\textbf{Dark}[Bias]}}
 odd pixel values $n$ : & \textbf{Dark}[Bias]$_\frac{n+1}{2}$ \\
 even pixel values $n$ : & $\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\mathbf{Dark}\mathrm{[Bias]}_\frac{n}{2} + \mathbf{Dark}\mathrm{[Bias]}_{\frac{n}{2}+1}\right)$ \\
 \end{block}
 & \\
 \begin{block}{rc\Right{\}}{= Master-\textbf{Dark}$_\mathbf{Flat}$[Bias]}}
 odd pixel values $n$ : & \textbf{Dark}$_\mathbf{Flat}$[Bias]$_\frac{n+1}{2}$ \\
 even pixel values $n$ : & $\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\mathbf{Dark}_\mathbf{Flat}\mathrm{[Bias]}_\frac{n}{2} + \mathbf{Dark}_\mathbf{Flat}\mathrm{[Bias]}_{\frac{n}{2}+1}\right)$ \\
 \end{block}
\end{blockarray}

\subsection{Survey}
...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: a `{` to close the preamble? :-)

Comment: @David Carlisle: The space of braces is not connected; an open brace can be closed. Seriously, thanks for pointing the mistyping, it's corrected now.

Comment: Aaah, that's how those brackets must be interpreted! `}{=` I thought that the `}` closes `{rc\Right{\}}` and the other bracket `{` closes the other. I did not know that `}{` needs to be interpreted as one.

Comment: It's simply tha the `\Right` command has two arguments: the extensible delimiter and the text that is centred w.r.t. this delimiter.

Comment: I am trying to move the whole structure inside the `blockarray` but do not succeed. `\centering` does not work in moving the structure to the middle of the page. What is the appropriate command?

Comment: Use the `center` environment, else the rest of the document will be centred. That said, \centering works, but you can't see it: the contents of the `blockarray` environments are wider than the page width. You'll see it in landscape mode.

Comment: Placing the `blockarray`-environment into a `center`-environment moves the `blockarray` too far right as if the page was 1.5 pages wide. You say that the `blockarray` is wider than a normal page. Is it maybe not centered on the page, but rather begins on the left side of the page? This would explain why the `center`-environment seems not to work as expected. I also tried to place the `block`-environment inside the `blockarray` inside a `center`-environment. Doesn't work too. `\qquad` works fine as emergency solution but other readers are probably interested in the center solution

Comment: @Lucas don't ask new questions in comments, if you need to ask a new question ask as new question on site but by default latex will not centre something that is wider than the specified text width excess width always sticks out on the right (and latex warns in the log). (There will be multiple answers on site giving example of that)

Comment: @Lucas: I have a (not perfect) workaround. See my updated answer.

Comment: @David Carlisle: Actually the centring default seems to be related to the fact that ‘comments’ on the right of braces have 0 width.

Comment: @Bernard who wrote that package;-)

Comment: @David Carlisle: It's precisely why I wrote this comment :o)